# Variables in Classes

Tags: php

I stumbled across a very wired error in php:

```
class A {
     public $var = "test";
     public function __construct() {
        $this->var = "test2";
        $b = new B;
        $b->method();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function method() {
        $c = new C;
        $c->method();
    }
}

class C extends B {
    public function method() {
        echo $this->var;
    }
}

$a = new A;
```

I get the output "test", but I do not know why, cause the variable var should be overwritten in Class A.

If I output $var in Class A it says "test2", if I output it in Class B it says "test"…

Comment: Can you please post the code you are using to test it?

Comment: This code will not really run correctly (missing `()` in class B) and won't output anything either, since you're not instantiating any objects. Can you please complete your example?

Comment: I forgot to add "$a = new Class A;" at the end.. Now it should work.

Comment: your code generates an error `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted` on my machine

Comment: How do you see `test` outputted, your code will cause an infinite recursion?

Comment: Can you show us the actual code that is causing the problem?

Comment: I dont have the real code here at all.. Above is just pseudo code to show the problem.. I initiate a variable in Class A. Class B extends Class A, and Class C extends Class B. Now I want to output the content of the variable var in Class A. But it always shows the default content and not the changed in Class A.. Can anyone follow me?

Comment: @lovelyday1 See my updated answer; also try out the demo

Comment: The [sample code](http://sscce.org/) still isn't representative. You don't need to post the actual code, but the sample code should reproduce the behavior you're experiencing. Make sure you run the sample code to confirm this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code on your question won't work because of the circular references (eg: `$b = new B` in `A`'s constructor), which will cause PHP to run out of memory. You really shouldn't be instantiating children classes in a parent class.

That being said, by what you are describing, it sounds like you are defining a constructor in `B`, which overrides the parent constructor. In PHP children classes don't implicitly call the parent constructor (unlike in languages like Java).

So, it just inherits the original value for `$var` (ie: `"test"`), which is never changed. If you are overriding `__construct()` in `B`, you'll have to explicitly call the parent constructor, like:

```
class B extends A {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

And that should give you `"test2"` when you do something like:

```
$b = new B;
echo $b->var;
```

#### See this demo: http://ideone.com/Q9Bp8

---

> What is the best way to have 3 classes, where the third and second can access variables of the first class?

The answer is, it depends on what you are doing. It sounds like you are not understanding how OOP works, which is a bigger problem. In general you only use inheritance when the children classes could reuse code from the parent class, and/or there is some sort of is-a or has-a relationship.

If your classes don't fit this model, just make the 3 classes independent, and hold a reference to the first class in your other classes. For example:

```
class A {
    public $n = 0;
    public function change($n) {
        $this->n = $n;
    }
}

class B {
    public function __construct($a) {
        $this->my_a = $a;
    }

    public function get() {
        return $this->my_a->n;
    }
}

$a = new A();
$b = new B($a):

echo $b->get();  // 0
$a->change(10);
echo $b->get();  // 10
```

#### See this demo: http://codepad.org/xL1Dzs0W

Comment: The original constructor is inherited. It's only *not* called if you override `__construct` in a child class, as for any other method.

Comment: By the description of the problem, I really think this is what's causing it. Let's see what the OP says.

Comment: So, what should I do than? What is the best way to have 3 classes, where the third and second can access variables of the first class?

Comment: @lovelyday1 What exactly are you trying to? Are you sure you need inheritance?

Comment: I want to have 3 classes, where the second and third one can access objects of the first on..